# .visible-xs not centering inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image inside a div, the div has the property `text-align:center;`

When I added `visible-xs` to my image it no longer centers in the div.

Any ideas why this is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.visible-xs-inline-block` or `.visible-xs-inline`

`.visible-xs` makes it a block element and a block element needs margin: 0 auto to center, whereas `.visible-xs-inline-block` and `.visible-xs-inline` will center with the `.text-center` class.

Learn about this here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities